# Unable to reach network while debugging Xamarin app on Kindle Fire

Tags: c#, xamarin, restsharp, kindle-fire

Original title: Consume REST calls when debugging Android app on Kindle Fire

*Now with more information, the original title doesn't grasp the issue*

---

I'm new to Android development and C# (I'm more accustomed to VB.net) so my apologies if this is an obvious question or if I'm phrasing things oddly.

I'm trying to make an application for my Kindle Fire that will issue REST commands when buttons are pushed to turn on a light. I've gotten it working to the point where the application loads on the Kindle and pushing the buttons changes the brightness, but when I replace the brightness code with the REST command it doesn't work.

I'm using:

1. Visual Studio 2015
2. Xamarin.Android for Visual Studio
3. Kindle Fire gen 5, FireOS 5.1.4
4. RESTSharp
5. Android SDK 5.1 API 22
6. Kindle USB ADB Drivers

Here's my MainActivity.cs:

```
using System;
using Android.App;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;
using RestSharp;

namespace Light_Console
{
    [Activity(Label = "Light Console", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {  
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

        Button but1 = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button1);
        but1.Click += (object sender, EventArgs e) =>
        {
            var client = new RestClient("http://192.168.1.124/api/********/lights/13/state");
            var request = new RestRequest();

            request.Method = Method.PUT;
            request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");
            request.Parameters.Clear();
            request.AddParameter("application/json", "{ \"on\":false }", ParameterType.RequestBody);

            var response = client.Execute(request);
            var content = response.Content;
        };
    }
  }
}
```

I've tried:

1. Running the same code as a desktop application, where it worked and the REST command went through when I clicked the button - very vexing.
2. Reinstalling the Android SDK - no luck
3. A different Kindle - nope
4. Enabling EVERY permission in the Android manifest thinking that was blocking access to the network - nada. (NOTE: I already had the INTERNET permission enabled)
5. Another sample application from Xamarin that uses the network to get weather, but this didn't resolve either.
6. Running the app after disconnecting the USB, still nothing.

**Since the original post, I've tried:**

7. Stepping through the app and received no errors and no obvious signs of an issue, it still just doesn't work.
8. Tried debugging to the Android Emulator and in that environment the app works fine and the lights turn off.

<s>Is it possible to access the internet in an app that's being debugged, or is that blocked somehow? If so, how does one allow this?</s>

**I now know it is possible to access the internet while debugging**

If anyone has any suggestions to try, I'd love to hear them.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, you can access the internet while debugging.  You haven't specified what error or exception, if any, that you're getting, or which line is generating the error.  Have you stepped through the code in the debugger?  If it's a connectivity issues, have you tried connecting to the server from the device's browser?

Comment: When I click the button nothing happens, I'm not presented with an error and it doesn't throw an exception. I have not tried stepping through the code, I just started the debugger. I'll give that a try when I get back from work. I can connect to a different webserver i have on the network using the Silk browser, but I don't know how to add the raw json to the request.

Comment: You need to debug it.  Step through the code, add some try/catch, etc.  Look at the server logs and see if the server is receving a request.  Try adding a simple GET method on your server and try calling that.

Comment: Okay I did the debugging. I went through each step using the Android emulator, rather than the Kindle, and it worked! I then tried the same steps again on the Kindle and no luck. I also did a GET request to the server in Silk and it worked no problem. So I'm sure the code works, at least on an emulator, and I'm sure the Kindle can send the commands through a browser. Weird, right? I'll give it a shot on an old phone i have, just gotta find the battery. Maybe Kindles are just too locked down?

Comment: do you get anything in the response.Content? do you receive anything on the server? Also, as you're hitting a 192.168.1.124 is the Kindle also on that network?

Comment: response.Content comes back blank. I tail'd the log on the server while I ran it in the Android emulator and I see it authenticating and running the command. When I run it from the Kindle, nothing shows up in the logs. The Pi hosting the server and the Kindle are on the same network and in the same VLAN with all traffic open between them. When I do a GET request from the browser in the Kindle it returns the expected response, a bunch of info about the specific bulb, so a PUT request should work as well. It's a real noggin scratcher.